# Jquery Mobile: code to select list of friends (Select list with filter)

Tags: list, select, jquery-mobile

I was wondering whether I can obtain a select list with a data-filter. I am aiming to allow the user to select list of friends (obtained via Facebook) to send invitations to.

I found that in the list view we can have a search filter bar; problem: cant multiple select
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html

And in the form list, we can select multiple items; problems: no search filter
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/selects/ - under "An example of a select with a long list of options:"

I want to find a combination of both, as in have a page with a big list of items that I can select multiple items (in this case friends) and have the ability to search thru them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Menu.
2. Search Filter Bar
3. A function to copy the select menu value to the Search Filter Bar
4. In the same function, simulate `Keyup` to run the filter and clear Search Filter Bar

```
$( "#seleMenuID" ).bind( "change", function() {

var val =  $('select option:selected').val();
$('.ui-input-text').val(val); //put value of select menu on search bar Filter


function simulateKeyUp(character) { //simulate keyup to run the filter
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keyup', which : character.charCodeAt(0) });
}

$(function() {
$('body').keyup(function(e) {

});

simulateKeyUp("e");
$('.ui-input-text').val(''); //clear filter search bar

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a listview and add a checkbox to each entry in the list. That way, when the user sees a filtered list, they can additionally check the items they want to select.

Comment: Use the existing list view and add checkboxes. Some custom code, yes.

Comment: Sorry that was my feeble attempt at humor.